# Database Offline Sync with Online Server with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, offline

I would like to know the best way to make a system, or if you already have something ready on the internet that anyone knows.

I want to develop a work order system for multiple technicians.

I will have a responsible server to receive the technical work orders

The computers of technical'll install xampp package with php and mysql, it will have access to his screen to enroll their own work orders on a computer without internet.

When he connect to the internet, it can send that work orders saved to the server online

As is done today? tips? ideas? something ready on the internet that I have not seen yet?

And another thing is if you need to update the php files, what now? the system needs to update the files case suffer any change ....

So guys, my questions are these, as is done, the better way is also question of safety for him not to have access to the server based, it only just a connection to the server ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too broad, however I think you shouldn't use PHP for something like this. JAVA or C++ would suit the job better in my humble opinion. However, if you are forced to use PHP I would suggest you to use simple SQLite databases instead of MySQL or whatever. In this way the whole database is centralized in a file, and once connected to the Internet your script can send (manually) the file to the main server which will integrate the database in the main one. Updating your PHP is a "big" issue, it involves practice with remote file-handling. Usually, you compress your update in an archive on the main server and distribute it through a script. Another script on the client-side check periodically for updates, when it finds one it downloads, and extract files to the client, thus achieving your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible with phpmyadmin database replication option. 
follow the link :

http://lewiscarr.co.uk/2013/07/moodle-mysql-replication-phpmyadmin/

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this wont work, if i update database, i will need to make some more stuff, like, moving id_something to cd_something (some logics)..